# Word2vec classification and clustering tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, nlp, word2vec, text-classification

I am trying to cluster some sentences using similarity (maybe cosine) and then maybe use a classifier to put text in predefined classes.

My idea is to use tensorflow to generate the word embedding then average them for each sentence. Next use a clustering/classification algorithm.

Does tensorflow provide ready to use word2vec generation algorithm?

Would a bag of words model generate a good output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- **No**, tensorflow does not provide a **ready-to-use word2vec** but it does have [a tutorial on word2vec](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/word2vec).
- **Yes**, a bag of words can generate surprisingly good output (but not *state-of-the-art*), and has the benefit of being **amazingly faster**.  I have a small amount of data (tens of thousands of sentences) and have achieved F1 scores of >0.90 for classification.

Comment: Well I found out about Tensorflow not having a ready to use for word2vec or glove. They provided a tutorial for implementing a word2vec model. I took a look at DL4J (JAVA) and I think I am going to stick with that for the moment.